# GNOME-shell using 15-30% CPU only on my user account

Tags: gnome-shell

Today, my Gnome-shell suddenly started using 15-30% CPU constantly.

If I start a session as another user (a new one), the CPU use is normal (1-2%). I have tried to deactivate extensions, but I still have the same problem.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I have emptied the list of apps to be launch when beginning a session. After doing that I restarted and all is ok now.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some instructions on how to do that to your answer? That would make it more useful to new users?